# how do i perform method for all iteration of for loop

Tags: android

my code just delete 1st file using button click but i want to delete and unhide all images using for loop if this statement is true  if(CheckArr[i] == true)  but my code just perform only first index file ot all checked file is  delete only 1st one is delete what do i do? how do i delete and copy all checked item? how do i customize my for loop??

```
    unhide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

for (int i = 0; i < CheckArr.length; i++) {
if (CheckArr[i] == true) {

db = new DataBase(getBaseContext());
    try {
    db.createDataBase();

      } catch (IOException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  Cursor DataC = db .selectQuery("SELECT path FROM Photos where name ='"+ 
  currentFiles[i].getName() + "'");



Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile.decodeFile(new File(root + "/"+ currentFiles[i].getName()));

try {       
 FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new 
 File(DataC.getString(DataC.getColumnIndex("path"))));

    outputStream.write(decodeFile.getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap));
outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

File file = new File(root + "/" + currentFiles[i].getName());
file.delete();

inflateListView(currentFiles);


DataC.close();
   db.close();
}
}
```

Comment: my code just delete 1st value of checked item  not all values

Comment: Please try to improve your question.. It's not clear as what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: i wanna say my code just copy and delete only current[i] value not all checked values i want to delete all files which check are true

Comment: how do i save values of CheckArr[i] == true in array

Comment: This is formatted much better but please delete your old question. You didn't need to open a new post but just formatted your other one like I asked

Comment: Have you checked that the length is greater than one and taken steps to debug and see if it enters the loop a second time?

Answer (score 0):

I would do my loop differently.  I'd only open the database once, and I'd check to see if the intermediate steps are working.

This is more what I'd recommend:

```
  unhide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            try {
                db.createDataBase();
                for (int i = 0; i < CheckArr.length; i++) {
                    if (CheckArr[i] == true) {
                        db = new DataBase(getBaseContext());
                        Cursor dataC = db.selectQuery("SELECT path FROM Photos where name ='"+
                                currentFiles[i].getName() + "'");
                        Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile.decodeFile(new File(root + "/"+ currentFiles[i].getName()));
                        if (dataC.moveToFirst() && bitmap != null) {
                            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new
                                    File(dataC.getString(dataC.getColumnIndex("path"))));

                            outputStream.write(decodeFile.getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap));
                            outputStream.close();

                            File file = new File(root + "/" + currentFiles[i].getName());
                            file.delete();
                        } else {
                            if (bitmap == null) {
                                Log.v("YOUR TAG", "bitmap not found");
                            } else {}
                            Log.v("YOUR TAG", "unable to convert file");
                        }
                        dataC.close();
                    }
                }
                db.close();

                inflateListView(currentFiles);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what you are doing on some things, but that's the direction I'd go in.